# How to search a string/word in a hyperlink:Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to search a word upload in the URL as "http://res.cloudin.com/sync/image/upload/IMG_8_Jul_2017_10:58:08_pm.jpg".
Later need to replace upload with some other word like w4_c.h_fit in the same link.
Matcher is not able to find upload.
Need help

My code is as below:

```
     String updatedStr;
     String keyword1="upload";
     String keyword2="IMG";

     String regex1 = "\\b"+keyword1+"\\b";
     Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(regex1);
     Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(str);
     int endUpload = matcher1.end();
     String str1 = str.substring(0,endUpload);

     String regex2 = "\\b"+keyword2+"\\b";
     Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile(regex2);
     Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(str);
     int startImg = matcher2.start();
     String str2 = str.substring(startImg);

      updatedStr = str1 + "w_0.5,h_0.5,c_fit" +str2;
```

Comment: have you tried a simple indexOf, or replace?

Comment: do you really need regex???

Comment: Please give exact input/output required this is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Like Stultuske said, use a replace instead when you only have static characters e.g.

```
String str = "http://res.cloudin.com/sync/image/upload/IMG_8_Jul_2017_10:58:08_pm.jpg";
String keyword1="upload";
String keyword2="IMG";
String updatedStr = str.replace("/"+keyword1+"/", "/"+keyword2+"/");
```